# Returning errors from classes in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

Suppose I have an interface like so:

```js
class Something {
    constructor(things) {
        if (things) {
            doSomething();
        } else return { errorCode: 1 }
    }
}
```

Is this code ok? In TypeScript I get an error similar to `property errorCode does not exist on type Something`. What would be an alternative way to do this? Here is something that I thought of:

```js
class Something {
    constructor(things) {
        if (things) {
            doSomething();
        } else this.error = { errorCode: 1 }
    }
}
```

Both of them have the same effect. But I would like to know which approach is better.

Comment: Why are you using interface?

Comment: @epascarello is right. Why use interface? Use Classes.`An interface defines the syntax that any entity must adhere to.` That is its intended purpose.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQA0Vw), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.  Right now your code is invalid TypeScript so it's hard to make any suggestion here whatsoever.

Comment: I'm so sorry @epascarello , I wrote interface instead of class. I will fix it.

Comment: So just define error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So define error as part of your class

```
interface MyError {
  errorCode: number;
}

class Something {
    private error: MyError;
    constructor(things) {
        if (things) {
            doSomething();
        } else this.error = { errorCode: 1 }
    }
}
```